# How do I let go of ED-E?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

As per title I lost the ED-E somewhere... Not sure where. I stopped paying attention to him because he seems to always get stuck at the entrance of various caves/vaults (would follow me just fine outside).
I never gotten message of his death. He does not show on the map. I still have the Enchanted Senses perk on my list. Boomers still offer to take care of my robot problem. The followers/BOS upgrades were done long ago.
Checked Lucky 38 and Primm - he is not there.

I actually kinda like this because I play sneak/sniping character and the silly eye-bot is a bloody aggro machine. The only reason I recruit him in the first place is his perk and extra carrying weight.

However this presents a problem: I can't recruit Rex because I can't let go ED-E.

Anything else I can try other than console commands?

Comment: The Question might be duplicate to this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/missing-companion-veronica-in-fallout-new-vegas  Try the suggested answers there and you will be able to get your ED-E back (and then dismiss it ;)

Comment: right, so basically reset NPC via console, which is kinda what I don't wanna do for exactly the reason described in that topic :(

Comment: I had this problem with ED-E on the PS3. He disappeared for ages and no ammount of fast travel or sleeping would bring him back. Then he just re-appeared randomly when I was at Hidden Valley.

Comment: @liho1eye, Iceag's already linked you to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/missing-companion-veronica-in-fallout-new-vegas) question, my answer given there (ignoring the console elements) is to **try using the elevator in Vault 22** - it must perform some sort of "reset" of your companions (this is presumably the effect David has seen as well, just elsewhere). I can confirm it works on PC, as I lost Rex last week and this worked like a charm to get him back.

Comment: @DMA57361 thanks I didn't notice that part before. I tried that just now and unfortunately that didn't help either... Even being teleported to the final battle didn't help. Oh well, the game is done, thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: @liho I've since edited my answer on the other question to make it more clear; it maybe was a little uneven for PC readers. Anyway - did you happen to try the console as well? Maybe you've found a more severe version of this kind of bug...

Comment: @DMA57361 No I haven't tried the console. The problem with using console commands is that once you started it is hard to stop, and I'll probably end up adding myself all the cool items and opening all key-locked doors with it. Its a game killer... I'd rather pretend it didn't exist.

Comment: @liho, a fair point - effectively the same reason why I wondered about for a few hours with Rex missing until I found Vault 22 to try the trick there.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on the PC version, open [the console](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_console_commands) (which is essentially the same as [Fallout 3's console](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_console_commands)) and set ED-E as your target in the console - using the `prid` command - and `moveto` him to you. I lost some of my companions at one point and doing this got them all back.

Console commands:

```
prid 001732d1
moveto player
```

The refid will be different if you have upgraded ED-E. You can see all his refids [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/ED-E).

Type the commands into the console, save the game, then exit and restart Fallout New Vegas - Steam achievements will be enabled again and ED-E will be with you.