# Where can I retrieve Cass from? (Or how to remote-dismiss a follower)

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I had Rose of Sharon Cassidy following me for a while, and asked her to wait behind while I cleared out the Van Graffs.

However she's now removed herself to a location on the map just North-West of the El Rey Motel. If I walk there she's nowhere to be seen. Ideally I'd like to find her (particularly as she's holding some of my inventory!).

If this isn't possible - or no-one else has come across this particular glitch - does anyone know a way I can dismiss a follower without having to talk to them? I tried to re-recruit Raul but he maintains that she's still hanging around.

Comment: Literally minutes after I post this, after being without Cass for hours and hours in-game, I start to do the Hoover Dam-related quest, which has automatically moved her to the Mojave Outpost. Unbelievable! While my Cass-centric question is now irrelevant, if anyone knows a way to remote-dismiss that could be handy...

Comment: Similar: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/lost-my-ed-e-somewhere. That said, the remote-dismiss hasn't been addressed here yet, AFAIK.

Comment: Heh, I'd previously lost my ED-E right at the start of the game too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no way in-game to remotely dismiss a companion. The closest to it are console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As of July 2011](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_patch_1.4.0.514) (360 patch 1.4.0.514, PS3 patch 1.06, PC patch 1.4.0.525), there are two [Companion Dismissal Terminals](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Companion_dismissal_terminal) in the game. One is mounted on the side of the Gun Runners kiosk and the other is next to the casino floor elevator of the Lucky 38. Activating one will send your active companion(s) back to their original locations, regardless of their current location or status.

If you're playing a pre-patch version of the game, there is no way to remotely dismiss a companion in the course of normal gameplay. The only way to dismiss a companion is to use dialog options to tell him/her to return to either the Lucky 38 or the character-specific home location.

Answer (score 1):

You can remote dismiss from a terminal directly next to the Gun Runners Vendortron.

Edit: Only if you have the GunRunners DLC

Comment: Only if you have the Gun Runner's Arsenal DLC

Comment: @AliceRees Wasn't sure on that. I've always played with it, heard too many awesome things about it, so I've never NOT had it there.

Comment: The bit about Gun Runners Arsenal isn't accurate. This terminal was introduced in a patch to the original game that came out relatively late, possibly around the time GRA was released.