# Followers have gotten stuck and disappeared

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So, Boone and Rex have been following me for some time now, and Boone is carrying quite a lot of valuables for me.

All of a sudden...when I loaded up my game today....they were not behind me.  I see their markers on a random spot on the map (that I had not travelled to yet), and I don't see them when I get there.

Some kind of glitch, or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some options for finding my lost companion Veronica, besides a manual search?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/what-are-some-options-for-finding-my-lost-companion-veronica-besides-a-manual-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found my answer in the [talk section of the fallout wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Fallout:_New_Vegas_companions).  Seems that when I had entered a fight in the Thorn, they stopped following me, and then their position on the map became completely random.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes followers glitch and teleport themselves to a random spot on the map.  Have you tried fast travelling to somewhere you've been?  Usually they will pop in like magic as soon as you arrive.

An alternate solution, which appears to work even if you've told them to wait, is to use the elevator in Vault 22 to go to the 5th level:

Occasionally they will glitch into an area where they die (and you're generally notified when this happens).  If they're dead, the best you can do is console commands, assuming you're on the PC.  [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10225/what-are-some-options-for-finding-my-lost-companion-veronica-besides-a-manual-s) has a list of the proper console commands required to bring them back.

Comment: I'm not sure whether a patch or one of the DLC's added this, but there's also a terminal over next to the Gun Runners Robot that will dismiss any companions that are currently 'following' you and send them back to their default positions. It's worth a try.

Comment: The Companion Dismissal Terminal appeared in one of the more recent patches.

Comment: Heh, seems I need to level up again before I can repair the elevator.  Vault 22 is very interesting to wander through though...great little side story.

Comment: ok, leveled up my repair enough to do this and they did not appear :(

Comment: nice, a glitch that fixes another glitch.